# How to convert formatted text to XML in C++

Tags: c++, xml

I have read a text file in, and now we need to convert the received input to XML data.

E.g.: Reading a text file yields:

```
English        100
Science         80
Computers       77
```

Now we need the output as:

```
<head>
    <English>100</English>
    <Science>80</Science>
    <Computers>77</Computers>
</head>
```

How can we achieve this?

Comment: -1: "does not show any research effort"

Comment: XSLT might be better suited for the task.

Comment: No, this is not a homework ! But can you help the needy rather than posts saying things which aren't useful.

Comment: Have you seen that guy who posted `-1: "does not show any research effort"`? I.e., have you tried anything, like, searching with [this page](http://google.com) or at [this site](http://stackoverflow.com/)? If so, what problems came up? Ask _specific_ questions.

Comment: And by the way: If you answer someone, add "@<his exact name>" to it. Otherwise he/she'll never be notified, e.g. @phresnel .

Comment: Um, are you trying to troll this group with such responses?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is, after reading the text file append `<` and `>` to the subject.

If `fout` is the output `std::filestream`, `subject` is a `std::string`, and
`score` is `int` or `unsigned`:

```
fout << "<head>" << std::endl;    
while (/* file is not finished */)
{
    // Read a string and an int from the file

    subject.insert(0,"<");
    subject.insert(subject.size(),">");
    fout << subject << score;

    subject.insert(1,"/");
    fout << subject<< std::endl;
}

fout << "</head>" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TinyXML:
[Here](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/)

Does all the things you need, in only 4 source files - simple stuff too:

```
void build_simple_doc( )
{
    // Make xml: <?xml ..><Hello>World</Hello>
    // Warning - this code isn't exception safe!
    TiXmlDocument doc;
    TiXmlDeclaration * decl = new TiXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "", "" );
    TiXmlElement * element = new TiXmlElement( "Hello" );
    TiXmlText * text = new TiXmlText( "World" );
    element->LinkEndChild( text );
    doc.LinkEndChild( decl );
    doc.LinkEndChild( element );
    doc.SaveFile( "madeByHand.xml" );

    delete decl;
    delete element;
    delete text;
}
```

Creates

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Hello>World</Hello>
```

Comment: -1: You demonstrate leaking code. Don't forget how many lurkers are here that are not experienced to see those leaks and take your code for correct.

Comment: @phresnel - Right you are - I just got the code from the tutorial page. Anyway, it's fixed now. Not exception safe though. 'Lurkers' might not know how to use auto_ptrs.

Comment: Interesting demonstration of bad-code-internet-propagation. --1.